# Use enter to submit search in Javascript alongside Button without refreshing page

Tags: javascript

I just want to use javascript, so no jQuery.
I currently have:

```
var button = document.getElementById('add_button');
button.addEventListener('click', search);
button.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
    if (event.which === 13) {
        search();
        return true;
    }
});
```

This is the html:

```
    <form>
    <input type="button" id="button" value="">
    </form>
```

It is just refreshing the page whenever I click enter though - any ideas?

Comment: You are assigning it for the button? Show your full code. Include HTML, JavaScript in a [mcve].

Comment: Is your button type set to submit?

Comment: I don't think so, if I use <button type="submit" id="button"> instead then the normal clicking of the button doesn't work and refreshes the page.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use `preventDefault()` property.

```
button.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.which === 13) {
      search();
      return true;
   }
});
```

Comment: The question is confusing. How can someone need a keyup on the button?

Comment: The page is still refreshing when I click enter, would you mind glancing at the html I added - maybe that is causing the issue?

Comment: @Jess, You cannot trigger a `keyup` event on `button` element. You should use an `input type="text"`.